# How can i have clean code for Html forms using some GUI builder in Linux? Like you can do using Dreamweaver in Windows

Tags: html, linux, ide

How can i build clean code for Html forms, tables etc in Linux with some GUI builder or tools. Like there is a Windows tools such as dreamweaver.

Thank you

Comment: And since when Dreamweaver generates clean HTML code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but the only way to have good clean HTML code is to write your own code manually.

To do it, you will need two things to start:

- A good code editor that facilitates typing, like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) does. It can also be some more complex IDE, like [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), [Netbeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netbeans), [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodevelop) etc.
- A strong desire to learn the web standards, using official sources such as the [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: Petru: Did you used DreamWeaver? Where you see the layout and place button, text, textarea and design it by watching what is happening instead of guessing the design with coding? Such GUI builder for Html i am looking for. I tried your Notepad++, Eclipse, NetBeans, MonoDevelop none have this. Any other recommendations please?

Comment: @Sonia, you asked a HTML designer that generates clean code. But there isn't! If you want clean code, I gave the answer: use a code editor and learn how to write good code by yourself. But if you only want to drag and drop things (what it's never clean code) and likes so much of DreamWeaver, why you don't use it on Linux with [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software))?

Comment: Some people are still pathetic downvoting without explanation while the answer is very well done.